# Secure Execution of Possibly Insecure Code Within Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, security

Currently, I am working on a function within a project that requires me to load code that is stored in an online database. The code should be moderately trusted, but not entirely.

We currently use md5 sums of the field in a seperate non-obvious table to ensure the code we're executing hasn't been changed, but we'd also like to sandbox the code as well with pysandbox (also accepting better suggestions). The issue comes when we have to use django models to get information from the database, as pysandbox always excepts when we try to touch models.

Secured Executer:

```
for hash in HashedChecksum.objects.all():
    if code_md5hash == hash.data:
        sandbox = Sandbox(SandboxConfig('stdout'))
        config.allowModule(contacts.models, Suppliers)
        namespace = {'query_dict': query_dict}
        sandbox.execute(code, locals=namespace)
        print namespace
    else:
        assert False
```

Code to be Executed:

```
print "code in sandbox"
try:
    import contacts.models
    print "hey"
    print contacts.models.Supplier.objects.all()  #line that excepts
except:
    print "Excepted"
print "Ended Execution"
```

Example with exception output:

```
try:
    import jmsdirectory.contacts.models
    print jmsdirectory.contacts.models.Supplier.objects.all()
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Exception output:

```
5.5
SafeModule 'jmsdirectory' has no attribute 'contacts'
5.6
{'e': AttributeError("SafeModule 'jmsdirectory' has no attribute 'contacts'",), 'company': u'D5202F00-A8C7-11E1-B68A-00219B15530E', 'jmsdirectory': <SafeModule 'jmsdirectory' from 'C:\\Joinerysoft\\Development\\joinerysoft-directory\\jmsdirectory\\..\\jmsdirectory\\__init__.pyc'>, 'contact': u'D53D7B00-A8C7-11E1-A34B-00219B15530E', 'address': u'D53368E1-A8C7-11E1-AF74-00219B15530E', 'type': u'stays'}
run_code: 6
[08/Jun/2012 15:53:01] "POST /transfer/server/ HTTP/1.0" 200 129
```

Comment: can you remove the `except` and post the exception it is throwing?

Comment: @dm03514 is right: eating the specifics of the exception makes debugging this type of stuff very difficult.

Comment: no, as without the try/except the pysandbox doesn't run

Comment: you could do `except Exception as e: print e` -- then you'd at least know what the exception is.